# How do I make a scrollable scrollbar?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, scrollbar, frames

I get a scrollbar on myscreen , but when I use it my page stays still, but my scroll bar moves!. How do I correct my code to move my page using scrollbar?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
root=Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, bd=0,height=1000,width=1000,scrollregion=(0,0,1500,1500))
frame = Frame(canvas, bd=2,height=1500,width=1500,bg='salmon',relief=SUNKEN)
frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
hbar=Scrollbar(root,orient=HORIZONTAL)
hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
hbar.config(command=canvas.xview)
vbar=Scrollbar(root,orient=VERTICAL)
vbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)


canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True,fill=BOTH)
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))
L = Label(frame, text=" NAME OF THE STUDENT ",font=('segoe script', 20,'bold'),bg='yellow2',fg='maroon',relief='raised',bd=9)
L.place(relx=0.05,rely=0.5)


L1 = Label(frame, text=" USER NAME ",font=('segoe script', 20,'bold'),bg='yellow2',fg='maroon',relief='raised',bd=9)
L1.place(relx=0.05,rely=0.6)
E1 = Entry(frame, bd =10,width=20,selectborderwidth=2,relief='groove',font=('segoe script', 20,'bold'),fg='maroon')
E1.place(relx=0.35,rely=0.6)



L2 = Label(frame, text=" PASSWORD ",font=('segoe script', 20,'bold'),bg='yellow2',fg='maroon',relief='raised',bd=9)
L2.place(relx=0.05,rely=0.7)
E2 = Entry(frame, bd =10,width=15,selectborderwidth=2,relief='groove',font=('segoe script', 20,'bold'),fg='maroon',show='*')
E2.place(relx=0.35,rely=0.7)



L3 = Label(frame, text=" CONFIRM PASSWORD ",font=('segoe script', 20,'bold'),bg='yellow2',fg='maroon',relief='raised',bd=9)
L3.place(relx=0.05,rely=0.8)
E3 = Entry(frame, bd =10,width=15,selectborderwidth=2,relief='groove',font=('segoe script', 20,'bold'),fg='maroon',show='*')
E3.place(relx=0.55,rely=0.8)



stud_bt=Button(frame,text=' CREATE ACCOUNT ',font=('segoe script', 11,'bold'),height=2,width=15,bg='dark orchid4',fg='floralwhite',bd=8)
stud_bt.place(relx=0.39,rely=0.9)

frame.pack()
root.mainloop()"""
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide minimal-reproducible-example, there seems to be a lot of code for your question. Also please do some research before asking, there are quiet a lot of simliar questions to yours at SO. Last but nut least, check your code for "onFrameConfigure" in the link.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not able to get it right. How do I modify the program? Kindly help me with that.

Comment: @Atlas435 . Pls help me out .

Answer (score 1):

You must set the `scrollregion` after adding all of the content to the canvas. Otherwise the scrollregion will be `None`.

Also, you can't use `pack` to put the frame in the canvas. You must use the `create_window` method of the canvas. You can only scrollitems created by the canvas, not items added with `pack`, `grid`, or `place`.

Comment: Thank You Bryan!! Can you please tell me how to modify my code?